# Using JavaScript Regular Expressions to remove HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I am new to regular expressions and am attempting to create different regular expressions to practice doing so. My question is, how would I go about using regular expressions to remove all HTML tags from a section of a page? For example, if I have the following snippet:

```
    <p>Hello, <b>my</b> name is <a href="#">Aaron</a></p>
```

How would I go about removing all of the tags so that my result is:
 Hello, my name is Aaron

So far I have tried using this:

```
    /<{1}[a-zA-z]+>{1}/ and /</{1}[a-zA-z]+>/
```

To try and get the different tags but when I try and run it, I only get the first

tag as the result. http://jsfiddle.net/x7aUx/1

Comment: Honestly, regular expressions suck for doing stuff like that, Instead, use the DOMParser tools that come with the browser. For practice and learning, I think that's awesome, but just keep in mind doing so in production would be naive and brittle. Hope this helps.

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: And yeh... even though you got an answer, it would still be awesome if you could [edit] to show what you tried, that way other people can see where you got stuck and learn from that. Think of it as your way of giving back to Stack Overflow as a question asker. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @MauricePerry - I love that post!  I didn't think to link that... awesome!

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I really didn't realize that it was bad to use regular expressions with HTML so I'll just try and find a way around it

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot guarantee anything in HTML, so this would probably be enough:

```
alert('<p>Hello, <b>my</b> name is <a href="#">Aaron</a></p>'.replace(/<.*?>/g,""));
```

It uses the regex `<.*?>` which matches everything between < and > including themselves and replaces them with empty string.

Parsing HTML using regex **is a bad idea** unless you are doing it for study purpose.

Answer (score 1):

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html:

```
result = subject.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, "");
```

- `<` matches the opening brace
- `[^>]*` matches any characters that is not a closing brace
- `>` matches the closing brace
- We replace with the empty string `""`